# How to position divs inline and custom position divs inside them?

Tags: css

How to get inline divs with scrollbar and other divs inside them. When I made just inline divs with scrollbar everything works fine, but when I try to put other divs inside everything collapse.
I need to have something like this:
[image]

Simple code:

```
<div class="inlineContainer">
  <div class="inlineDiv">
    <div id="customDiv1">inside div 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inlineDiv">
    <div id="customDiv2">inside div 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS 1(inline not working properly):

```
.inlineContainer{
  width:100%;
  height:150px;
  overflow:scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.inlineDiv{
  height: 100px; 
  width: 100px; 
  display: inline-block;      
  position:relative;
}
#customDiv1{
  position:absolute;
  left:10px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
#customDiv2{
  position:absolute;
  left:20px;
  width:60px;
  height:50px;
}
```

CSS 2(inline not working properly):

```
.inlineContainer{
  width:100%;
  height:150px;
  overflow:scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.inlineDiv{
  height: 100px; 
  width: 100px; 
  display: inline-block;      

}
#customDiv1{
  margin-top:50px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
#customDiv2{
  margin-top:10px;
  width:60px;
  height:50px;
}
```

CSS 3(scrollbar not working):

```
.inlineContainer{
  width:100%;
  height:150px;
  overflow:scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.inlineDiv{
  height: 100px; 
  width: 100px; 
  float:left; 
  position:relative;    
}
#customDiv1{
  position:absolute;
  left:20px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
#customDiv2{
  position:absolute;
  left:10px;
  width:60px;
  height:50px;
}
```

Comment: I've been trying it for hours. I can put all my attempts here, but it will be messy.

Comment: Well at least ONE attempt is required to be shown, Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `vertical-align: top;` to the inline-blocks to make them align at the top of their container:

```css
div {
border: 1px solid #777;
}
.inlineContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.inlineDiv {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#customDiv1 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#customDiv2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inlineContainer">
  <div class="inlineDiv">
    <div id="customDiv1">inside div 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inlineDiv">
    <div id="customDiv2">inside div 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```